# How to group data returned by Observable in Angular 4 with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm struggling grouping data coming from an observable with `Angularfire2`

For now, I got an array of value in a Firestore Document and for each, I return a Document. :

**My provider**

```
getUserActivites() {
    return this.afs.collection("users").doc(`${this.userId}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(list => {
        let event = list.payload.data().activities
        return event.map(e =>
          ({ activity: this.afs.doc(`activities/${e}`).valueChanges() })
        )
      })
    }
```

**My Component**

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.userActivities = this.agenda.getUserActivites()
    })
  }
```

**Then in my view**

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of userActivities | async">
        <div *ngIf="item.activity | async; let activity;">
            <p>{{ activity.start_date | amCalendar}}</p>
            <p><strong>{{ activity.name}}</strong></p>
            <p>{{ activity.description }}</p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

This above part works.

Then, I would like to group my data by value `start_date`. I try to create a basic `Angular Pipe` but the `.reduce()` function seems not able to handle an observable.
I also try to implement the `RxJs GroupBy` but without success.
Anyone could suggest a strategy here, on how to group by this Observable?

Comment: You mean to group the values so `userActivities` emits groups of value by date instead of single items?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I need `userActivities` to be an Observable emitting grouped value in order to render in the view data grouped by date.

Comment: Do these values already come in a sequential order? I mean, are they ordered?

Comment: No they're not ordered. They come in the order of the `list.payload.data().activities` which is a string identifier for each `activities`

Comment: Ok, so it's a little bit more complicated... I thought you could use something like `buffer` which would be fine if the values already came in order... I think you would have to keep a track of all the unique emitted dates and for each one either: 
(i) Create an Observable on demand if it's the first value for a given date and then emit the value
(ii) Just emit the value in the corresponding Observable stream.
So you would end up with a high order observable, where each emitted value is an Observable of values in a given date. Does it make sense?

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit lost here :) by returning only `this.afs.doc("activities/${e}").valueChanges()` instead of an object, I can see my single Observable, but how to unwrap them then?

Comment: Is there a way you can setup your current example, share a repo/plunker/etc? I'd like to take a look a little bit deeper

Comment: I try to set up a Plunker, but can't make it work. You can access it at this [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/EvYVeGtlMy7rEIWO7bHy/) I connect it to a test database with exact same format I use in my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161994/discussion-between-osman-cea-and-benoit).